# Counting the occurrences of numbers in a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.each(string.split(''), function(){
    if(!check[this]){
        count++;
        check[this]=true;
    }
})
```

For my function above, it's able to count the number of unique characters. For instance, for `1113`, the result would be 2, as there only 1 and 3. For `1134`, the result would be 3, as there 1,3 and 4.

But I want to for example 1133 and 1113, there are of the same 2 unique number which is 1 and 3. How do I count the max occurrence of 1 and 3? For `1133` it would be 2, while for `1113` it would be 3 as `1` appears 3 times.

I just need to count the occurrence of the most occur number in the string(number only).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the counts and find the max of the counts. Here is the code put into a function:

```
function getMostOccurrence(str) {
    var check = {};
    var maxOccurrences = 0;

    // This part you already have...kind of
    str.split('').forEach(function(num) {
        // Set it the first time
        if (typeof check[num] === 'undefined') {
            check[num] = 0;
        }

        // Increase it
        check[num] += 1;
    });

    // Find the max of that
    for (var num in check) {
        if (check.hasOwnProperty(num)) {
            if (check[num] > maxOccurrences) {
                maxOccurrences = check[num];
            }
        }
    }

    return maxOccurrences;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a couple of helpers:

```
// Given an object, it returns the values in an array
// {a:1, b:2} => [1,2]
var values = function(x) {
  return Object.keys(x).map(function(k){return x[k]})
}

// Given an array, it counts occurrences
// by using an object lookup.
// It will return an object where each key is an array item
// and each value is the number of occurrences
// [1,1,1,3] => {'1':3, '3':1}
var occurrences = function(xs) {
  return xs.reduce(function(acc, x) {
    // If key exists, then increment, otherwise initialize to 1
    acc[x] = ++acc[x] || 1
    return acc
  },{})
}

// Composing both helpers
var maxNumberOccurrence = function(n) {
  // To get the maximum value of occurrences
  // we use Math.max with `apply` to call the function
  // with an array of arguments
  return Math.max.apply(0, values(occurrences(n.toString().split(''))))
}

maxNumberOccurrence(1113) //=> 3
```

Comment: Your approach looks more sophisticated. Would you mind commenting/explaining it so we can all learn what is happening here without manually decoding it?

Comment: Very nice. Though I am wondering if there's any reason you used `Array.prototype.reduce` here as the iterator?

Comment: Because I don't like `for` loops, they are troublesome, and ugly.